# How to cut while Grepping

Tags: centos, text-processing, grep

current input is from the command

```
grep -i "final_model" /dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/assemble.preprocessing
```

current output is:

```
final_model=</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001.inp>
```

required Output-1 is:

```
test_F00ME001.inp
```

required Output-2 is:

```
F00ME001
```

Comment: Please invest more time in writing your question. How does your input look like? How does the command you've tried looks like exactly?

Comment: And where does the output go? files? variables?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller : problem solved. Thanks for your contribution.
please remove "HOLD" from my question !!

Comment: @Nayak, I am unable to take your question off-hold on my own; there's a review queue dedicated to reopening questions. I personally would not vote to reopen the question yet as my question (in a comment above) has not been answered. Happy to hear you got an answer, though!

Comment: output is displayed on shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

```
final_model=</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001.inp>
```

is a line of text that your `grep` command is producing,

```
grep ... | sed 's#.*/##; s/>$//' | tee output1 |
           sed 's/^[^_]*_//; s/\..*//' >output2
```

This would save the two modified lines into `output1` and `output2`

Testing:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'final_model=</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001.inp>' |
  sed 's#.*/##; s/>$//' | tee output1 |
  sed 's/^[^_]*_//; s/\..*//' >output2
```

```
$ cat output1
test_F00ME001.inp
```

```
$ cat output2
F00ME001
```

The first `sed` call operates on the original data and first removes everything up to and including the last `/` character.  It then removes the `>` at the end.

The `tee` saves this into `output1` and also passes it on to the next stage of the pipeline.

The second `sed` call operates on the modified data and first removes everything up to and including the first `_` character.  It then removes everything from the first dot onwards and redirects the result into `output2`.

Comment: Thanks... output-1 works well, but Output-2 is ( model=</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001 )

Comment: @Nayak That's because you are running sed separately on the grep output. This is not what I'm doing. I'm running the second sed on the result of the first.

Comment: i have added second command with pipe (on output of first sed). now result looks like (test_F00ME001). what if i have more than one "_" symbol ?!

Comment: @Nayak Well, that depends on where it's located.

Comment: now, i have combined both sed commands, then with pipe added rev and cut...works well ( sed 's#.*/##; s/>$//;s/^[^_]*_//; s/\..*//' | rev | cut -d'_' -f1 | rev ). 
output is : F00ME001
:))))
Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @Nayak If you told me what your filenames _actually_ looks like (which is what you should have done from the start, in the question), I could probably come up with something better.

Comment: my alias looks like this;
alias inp 'tac /scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/$USER/\!:1/Simulation/Input/assemble.preprocessing | grep -im1 final | sed "s#.*<##; s/>$//"'

here \!:1 = some directory name (system generated).

I want 3 differen outputs in one command, as shown below;
1. /scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/qxd9236/SomeDiectoryName/Simulation/Input/E1_E_VABG_COIHSR64L_F08EK019.inp

2. E1_E_VABG_COIHSR64L_F08EK019.inp

3. F08EK019

Answer (score 1):

```
$ final_model="</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001.inp>"
$ o1=$(echo "$final_model" | sed -e 's/<\(.*\)>/\1/')   #remove <>
$ o1=$(basename "$o1")   #get basename (test_F00ME001.inp)
$ echo "$o1"
test_F00ME001.inp
$ o2=$(echo "$o1" | sed -e 's/test_\(.*\)\.inp/\1/')   #get text between test_ and .inp
$ echo "$o2"
F00ME001
```

Try more use google next time, you can find both commands answered somewhere.

`sed` command source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242517/7351855

Comment: Note that the `$final_model` string in tho question is enclosed in `<...>`, and that it's unclear whether that line shows a variable assignment or wether that line is just a piece of text coming out of `grep`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the point, I edited post to remove also <> from `final_model` string.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below commands to achieve same

```
final_model=</dir1/dir2/dir3/user/dir4/test_F00ME001.inp>

o1=`echo $final_model| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|sed "s/[^[a-zA-Z_0-9.]//g"`

echo $o1

o2=`echo $o1|awk -F [_.] '{print $2}'`

echo $o2

F00ME001
```

Comment: I prefer to not fix from the start position: awk -F [_\.] '{print $(NF-1)}'

Comment: You can _not_ have run that first line.  It contains a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `grep -i final_model` with perl, and you capture the data you need:

```
$ perl -nE '/^final_model=.*\/(test_([^.]+)[^>]+)/ && say "$1\n$2"' assemble.preprocessing
test_F00ME001.inp
F00ME001
```

The first set of capturing parentheses grabs the stuff after the last slash: `(test_([^.]+)[^>]+)`
The second set grabs the stuff between the underscore and the dot.

Then you can capture the 2 lines into variables with this construct:

```
{ read output1; read output2; } < <(
    perl -nE '/^final_model=.*\/(test_([^.]+)[^>]+)/ && say "$1\n$2"' assemble.preprocessing 
)
```

We are redirecting a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) into the grouping of 2 read commands.

```
$ echo "$output1"
test_F00ME001.inp
$ echo "$output2"
F00ME001
```

Comment: thanks for answer... i am avoiding additional script/language as Perl ( trying to execute with Shell).

Comment: Why? From the shell's perspective, perl and grep are both simply external commands: they are **not** *shell commands*. Are you looking for a *pure shell* solution? If yes, what shell and version are you using?